# Code skips the next MyRecipient when deleting the previous non-resolved recipient

Tags: vba, email, outlook

Sorry if this is confusing, I tried to explain the entire process the best I could...

The following code is part of a greater code that grabs names of people involved in a project and adds them to a variable named "myRecipients" which is dimensioned as Outlook.Recipients, and creates a notification email automatically. The other parts of the code appear to be working.

The code should delete the non-resolved name and save it to an array (ToralErrName) so that a message box can let the user know that they will have to manually add the non-resolved name in the outlook mail message. This code worked until I tried to add this check.

The problem is, when the current recipient is deleted, it removes that member from the array and the current position in "myRecipients" becomes the next in the array. So when the code gets to the "Next myRecipient" line, it will skip the current position (which would have been the next item before the current item was deleted) and go to the next recipient.

Does anyone have an idea on how to prevent this from happening? Normally, if this were a for loop with an integer value, ex "i", I would just add in something like "i=i-1", but I'm unfamiliar with how to go about this with an Outlook.Recipients variable. Thank you for any advice you might have!

```
    For Each myRecipient In myRecipients
         If Not myRecipient.Resolved Then
             If Not TotalErrName = "" Then
                 TotalErrName = TotalErrName & ", " & myRecipient.Name
             Else
                 TotalErrName = myRecipient.Name
             End If
             myRecipient.Delete 'Delete recipient if they are not found in the address book
         End If
    Next myRecipient

        MsgBox "The following names were not found in the address book and must be added manually: " & TotalErrName
```

Comment: The simple solution would be put those recipients to delete in a temporary collection, then delete them in an iteration on the collection.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's usually best to avoid changing a collection while looping over its contents: one approach (I see also suggested by A.S.H) is to add items to another collection for later processing:

```
Dim c As New Collection, r, sep

sep = ""
For Each myRecipient In myRecipients
     If Not myRecipient.Resolved Then
         c.Add myRecipient
         TotalErrName = TotalErrName & sep & myRecipient.Name
         sep = ", "
     End If
Next myRecipient

For Each r In c
    r.Delete
Next r

MsgBox "The following names were not found in the address book " & _
        "and must be added manually: " & TotalErrName
```

Comment: interesting. I'm not familiar with dimensioning a variable as a collection. So is it removing it from the myRecipients variable and transferring it over to the collection variable, or is it duplicating the name and then removing it via a reference back to the myRecipients variable?

Comment: I added it to the code and everything seems to be working perfectly now, thank you very much for the help!!!

Comment: Adding it to the collection doesn't remove it from myRecipients: it just stores a reference to the recipient object so it can be deleted letter using that reference.

Answer (score 0):

You are modifying the collection you are processing. Use a down loop:

```
For I = myRecipients.Count to 1 step -1
  set myRecipient = myRecipients.Item(I)
...
```